# gitignore all except file in sub-sub folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I already tried many combinations of the .gitignore but none worked for what I need. I have this tree:

```
jobs/
jobs/projecta/config.xml
jobs/projecta/garbage
jobs/projecta/more/garbage
jobs/projectb/config.xml
jobs/projectb/garbage
jobs/projectb/more/garbage
```

Garbage means any other file. I want to commit only the config.xml files, and ignore everything inside jobs/ except them. So I tried:

```
/jobs/*
!/jobs/*/config.xml
```

This way, everything inside jobs are ignored, including the config.xml file. With the inverse order, same happens. So, I can force add all config files and changes to them will be tracked, but if I add a new folder inside jobs, it's config.xml won't appear as a untracked file, so this way people can forgot to add them.

I already tried with **, but I got the same.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder) help?

Comment: Just a random guess:  I'd try `/jobs/*/*` in the first line.

Comment: @Zeeker No. I replaced the second level folder by *, new config.xml files aren't shown in untracked files.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Same thing, if I create a new config.xml it is not shown as a untracked file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [question I mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder) actually answers this scenario; the crucial part is the following:

> If a directory is excluded, Git will never look at the contents of that directory.

Which is just a rephrasing of this snippet from the [gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) documentation, emphasis mine.

> It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. **Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons**, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

---

Your pattern `/jobs/*` will ignore each file and folder in `jobs`. This means that git won't even look in this ignored folders to see if your `!/jobs/*/config.xml` pattern matches a file in them.

In turn you have to explicitly *unignore* the subfolders and then *reignore* the contents; after this you can again *unignore* your `config.xml` files. This might seem silly but that's how git handles ignores.

```
# Ignore everything in /jobs
/jobs/*
# Reinclude all folders in /jobs
!/jobs/*/
# Ignore everything in the subfolders of /jobs
/jobs/*/*
# Reinclude config.xml files in the first-level subfolders of /jobs
!/jobs/*/config.xml
```

This patterns will ignore everything but `config.xml` files in the first-level subfolders of `jobs`.

Comment: I understood the concept and in theory your example is right, but it does not work: https://gist.github.com/kassner/27f9ae2013928ee2d381 Something related to git version? I'm using `git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50)`

Comment: @RafaelKassner Sorry, I forgot to mention that you should avoid copying the comments and trailing whitespaces. They mess with the gitignore.

Comment: spaces really did made the difference is this case. It is fully working as I expected now. Thank you very much!

Comment: I generally just  put `!*/` at the end of `.gitignore` now and use `**` for trailing wildcards, list any directories I actually want to ignore after the `!*/`. `jobs/**!jobs/**/config.xml !*/`.